# Why CKEditor change original element and class

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor5

for example, I have following content will be used:

```
<div class="h21copy">
    <p>123</p>
</div>
```

When I initialize with CKEditor, it will become to:

```
<p>123</p>
```

screenshots blow:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

paste in your config.js

config.allowedContent = true;

Further reading:
https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/guide/dev_allowed_content_rules.html